# Linq query EntityCommandExeceptionException error

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

When I call 'api/test/name=stop,tap,app...(24 names values)' from the following query below, I am experiencing the an error:

```
"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply. Rewrite the query or break it up into smaller queries.","ExceptionType":"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
```

Linq Query:

```
        var data = db.database_bd.AsQueryable();

            if (query.startDate != null)
            {
                data = data.Where(c => c.UploadDate >= query.startDate);
            }

            // If any other filters are specified, return records which match any of them:
            var filteredData = new List<IQueryable<database_bd>>();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.name))
            {
                var ids = query.name.Split(',');
                foreach (string i in ids)
                {
                    filteredData.Add(data.Where(c => c.Name != null && c.Name.Contains(i)));
                }
            }
            // If no filters passed, return all data.
            // Otherwise, combine the individual filters using the Union method
            // to return all records which match at least one filter.
            if (filteredData.Count != 0)
            {
                data = filteredData.Aggregate(Queryable.Union);
            }
            if (!data.Any()) //line causing error
            {
                var message = string.Format("No data was found");
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message);
            }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);
        }
```

Query class:

```
public class Query
 {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> startDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> endDate { get; set; }
 }
```

I tried adding a range to the 'filterdata' method, but I could not get that to work. Any advice, would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: so you want datas with firstFilter (startDate) OR datas with other filters (query.name)  combined ?

Comment: I would like to be able to call (startDate) with the (name) parameter, but being able to filter many (name) parameter values (1-70), if possible.  so in answer -- datas with other filters (query.name) combined.  Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work?

```
var data = db.database_bd.AsQueryable();

if (query.startDate != null)
{
    data = data.Where(c => c.UploadDate >= query.startDate);
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.name))
{
    var list = query.name.Split(',');
    data = data.Where(pr => list.Any(pr2 => pr.Name.Contains(pr2)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am sorry to inform, the code above gave me the following error, 'API_09Oct.database_bd' does not contain a definition for 'list' and no extension method 'list' accepting a first argument of type 'API_09Oct.database_bd' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). I have tried adding (list) before, but it also gave me a similar error.

Comment: Oh sorry, think i had a typo on the last code line, obviously you need to access the list and not pr.list.

Comment: Sorry, I did try removing (pr.) originally and it gave me another error -- Delegate 'System.Func<API_09Oct.database_bd,int,bool>. Many thanks for your time and help.

Comment: That is odd, I just tested it locally and it works perfectly. Is there something odd about your domain model?

Comment: Yes, lower case s there, obviously you should be able to interpret the compiler errors.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [predicatebuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) for this (look at doc for "installation").

```
var data = db.database_bd.AsQueryable();

var mainPredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<database_bd>();


if (query.startDate != null)
    mainPredicate = mainPredicate.And(c => c.UploadDate >= query.startDate);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.name))
{
    var namePredicate = PredicateBuilder.False<database_bd>();
    var ids = query.name.Split(',');
    foreach (var id in ids) {
       namePredicate = namePredicate.Or(c => c.Name != null && c.Name.Contains(id));
    }
    mainPredicate = mainPredicate.And(namePredicate);
}
data = data.Where(mainPredicate );

if (!data.Any()) //line hopefully causing no more error
{
     var message = string.Format("No data was found");
     return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help and time into this.  I am sorry to inform, the query above is really slow and its not outputting results from the search criteria, instead dumping the entire dataset records. Please advice, if possible.